# How to insert a blank row in SQL at specified locations?

Tags: sql

I'm looking at the last 12 months. Each month is in the dataset 5 times, once for each Segment. Each row, (Segment, yearmonth) also has "calls". So each row looks like

```
Segment   YearMonth    Calls
1           201505       20
```

However, the segment is only in the row with the first month so it looks like this:

```
Segment   YearMonth    Calls
1           201505       20
            201506       20
            201507       20
            201508       20
            201509       20
2           201505       20
...
```

My question is, how can i get blank rows to insert before each new segment?
thanks!

Comment: This is horrible. Do not make records depend on info from another one like this

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to insert a row in a specific position.  The order of rows in a table is only defined if you specify an "order by" clause in your select statement (i.e., this isn't excel, the rows are not really in a specific order unless you tell them to be).  You probably want to create a query or a view to do this instead.

Comment: what dbms are you using ?

Comment: Don't confuse the data layer with the presentation layer

Comment: the reason i need the blank rows is because i am pulling this directly into excel into a chart and the formatting requires the blank rows

Answer (score 1):

SQL generally does not do formatting but Oracle SQL*Plus does.  If you are working with SQL*Plus and your query would return:

```
SEGMENT     YEARMONTH      CALLS
1           201505       20
1           201506       20
1           201507       20
1           201508       20
1           201509       20
2           201505       20
2           201506       20
```

You can enter:
    BREAK ON SEGMENT
before your query and get something like:

```
SEGMENT     YEARMONTH    CALLS
1           201505       20
            201506       20
            201507       20
            201508       20
            201509       20
2           201505       20
            201506       20
```

If you want to add a space after each SEGMENT, you can use:

```
BREAK ON SEGMENT SKIP 1
```

If you are using something other than SQL*Plus, you will need to say in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to return a blank row before each segment, some pseudo sql might be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(   
   SELECT segment
         ,yearmonth
         ,calls
   FROM table
   UNION 
   SELECT segment
         ,[yearmonth] = null
         ,[calls]     = null
   FROM 
   (
      SELECT distinct segment
      FROM table
   ) seg               
) base
ORDER BY segment
        ,yearmonth
```